# can you save a wireframe as a png?

Tags: modeling

i am trying for the first time to use blender to create a wireframe so i can turn an object into a 3d lamp, i have managed by tutorials to get the image to a wireframe only which is perfect for what i need, but then there is no way that i can find to save that image out of blender as a png etc with just the wireframe on its own without the model attached to it, is this at al possible please

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the 3D view menu, and choose viewport render image, which will render any combination of viewport overlays you activate.

[image]